# How to override Entity Framework entity get method ?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing something like this :

```
List<Employees> employees = DB_Context.Employees.Where(p => p.id == empId).ToList();
```

With the properties :

> ID
>
> FirstName
>
> LastName
>
> Address

I want to override the `Address` , and add some text before the real Address , 
for example the text : `Client's address` .

How can I return the string `Client's address` + **Address** property

?

Comment: You cannot override Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't want to "override Entity Framework", you want a projection. In LINQ you project using `Select()`:

```
var employees = context.Employees
                       .Where(p => p.id == empId)
                       .Select(e => new Employee
                       {
                           ID = e.ID,
                           FirstName = e.FirstName,
                           LastName = e.LastName,
                           Address = "Client address: " + e.Address
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

You could also expose a non-mapped property and instruct your colleagues to use that one:

```
public class Employee
{
    // Other properties

    [NotMapped]
    public string ClientAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return "Client address: " + Address;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want that , what would happen is someone will write a new function (some other function) ? the `Client address:` string will not appear!

Comment: Yeah so then you didn't describe your problem properly (read [ask]), and you're trying to fix this problem at the wrong level. Either fix this for example in a database view, or expose a method instead of the entire DbContext to your code's users.

Comment: @ CodeCaster : I described it perfect , people just didn't understand .

Comment: If nobody understands the speaker, maybe there is something wrong with someone? :)

Comment: @CodeCaster : Thanks , however , I know how to expand a property , but I can't use another property . I need to use the mapped property , and that's why I asked clearly - Override .

Comment: @ron we don't know what you know. You wouldn't be the first here to abuse terminology.

Comment: `CodeCaster` : Well , you right , I'm sorry for not being more clear .

Comment: @on maybe you'd want to update your question to include what are and aren't valid options. :)